# How to set the C include path when compiling the proj-sys crate?

Tags: rust

I am trying to use `proj` crate, but building `proj-sys` fails, not able to find C stdlib headers:

```
error: failed to run custom build command for proj-sys v0.12.2
/usr/local/include/proj.h:120:10: fatal error: 'stddef.h' file not found
```

After searching for a while, it seems that this issue is due to a different location of the include directory in different versions of gcc (or clang). I found how to provide the correct location to the C compiler, but how would I do it when building this crate with Cargo?

My gcc headers are in the `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.4.0/` folder, but I don't even know where they are looked for when the crate does its thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution to my problem. It was just to install `clang` package.

On Debian-like systems, it's just:

```
sudo apt-get install clang
```